# Send value of a variable from phone app to another phone real time

Tags: android

Im a little new to the android development, I believe I have the basics down but I am wondering the best way to communicate between two phones running the same app. I am looking for something that would be close to instant. For an example, if you sent a message or somekind of variable or string it would appear on the other phones app providing the app was open on both phones. Would be great if I could be pointed in the correct direction here, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have access to a server that both devices can connect to, the best way to handle this is to set up a socket and have both devices connect to it. That way the messages can be send back and forth and be pushed through immediately (rather than the devices polling for any new thing to do intermittently).

You can learn more about using sockets on android here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

If you're unfamiliar with how to write a server socket, you can write something that works somewhat similarly with a system that just has each device leave a message and have the other device come looking for it, but as I said, that is much less "real time" since then you have to have the devices constantly pestering the server to see if there's anything new to do.

There are also kludgy ways to create a fake socket behavior whereby the http connection never closes and you just keep sending data down the pipe, but if you can avoid it and just use a socket, you should.